# ACL controls not working with smart groups?

Tags: smartgroups, acl, 4.7

I submitted a bug on an ACL problem in Nov 2014. [CRM-15662](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15662). It was fixed in 4.5.5, and I tested it as working.

This appears to be broken again in 4.7.1. I have not tried to use this feature in a year so I don't know what happened since I last tested it as working. The organization needs this feature now. The target purpose is that chapter staff be able to view and edit their own members. A smart group is used to define the data they can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that the pull request https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/4708/files which Jitendra claimed fixed the issue is not in version 4.7.1. It seems that it may have caused an issue and was therefore backed out - but I have not sleuthed that far so I am only surmising.

It‘s a fairly straightforward fix - but I do not feel I understand the potential knock ons particularly if it did introduce this other bug or not.

Your options are:

1) Go ahead and apply that one line fix manually or have your sysadmin do it, and back up everything and test thoroughly.

2) Report it as a bug and wait for it to be addressed.

3) Report it as a bug and provide funds for a core team member to examine it sooner. Show the previous ticket and let them sleuth it out. As there is a fix already there it probably will not take long to confirm if it did cause the other issue, and if so prevent that.

4) Recruit your local CiviCRM partner agency to examine this for you and make the best decision for you and your client.

Comment: Looks like CRM-15750 undid the fix CRM-15662. So this leaves ACL with smart groups (a major feature) not working. I added a new bug CRM-18127.

Comment: This feature was one of the deciding factors to go with civicrm -- very disappointing that this didn't actually work. What do you think it would cost to fix this? I looked at the code -- my brain hurt. The php is spaghetti code tbh. I program c# and there is no comparison.

Comment: For the core team I've no idea. From me, very cheap! Email me at john@civifirst.com Please mark this q as answered :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this was an issue of misunderstanding. An ACL can have a target of a Smart Group, but the Group that contains the people who are permitted to access the target contacts must be a standard group.

The discussion was shifted to this [ticket](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18127) afaik.

Comment: No, this was never true. The permitted accounts are in standard groups.

Comment: Good news today is that I have retested this as working now. This is just one test, so more will be required. Weeks ago I believe I did the same steps and it only showed one contact. Followed these instructions, https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

Comment: Well, it's only working for some of the staff accounts. We have chapters, and each chapter staff role should only see their members. I have to analyze the differences between the configurations which will take some time.

Comment: Okay, after more checking I see that it is working for all staff accounts. Don't know why it was not working for me before.

Comment: Paul - can you help SE by +1 answers that have been helpful, and by ticking the better one where there are several - this is what drives SE being a good resource for people searching for similar issues. thx

Comment: I have not completely ruled out operator error as the original cause.